# Events are disabled in codenameone

Tags: events, codenameone

I have problem when I want to access events. I already copied the resource files (nativej2me.res) under src directory but still the events are disabled within my project.

Can anyone help me how to arrange the resources so it enables the vents..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't move that resource file. Its not the place for it.

I'm guessing you created a handcoded application where GUI builder events aren't supported. You need to create a GUI builder project when creating a new project.

That's a GUI builder project (notice the visual not manual in the brackets)
[image]

Comment: Can you guide me more,

I amusing Eclispe, so I go to create new project wizrd and then selct CodenameOne. Where is GUI biulders on eclipse? Thanks

Comment: Hi I create my projects the same in GUI Builder on eclipse but the events are still disabled..what is the problem?

Comment: In what OS and what directory is your workspace located?

Comment: Hi Shai, I am using windows 7 enterprice edition and I have atached the directory of my files..
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfRDW.jpg

Comment: Use the res file under the src directory, not that res file.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the googlers out there:

Have a look in the file codenameone_settings.properties - in there you'll find the property userClassAbs=something/StateMachine.java

Its an absolute path and it was showing the wrong directory. After fixing this I was able to add Events in the Designer again.